# How to join three tables with Laravel and keep data integrity

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.7 and now I am trying setup a relationship between three tables named:

- Tickets (PK - TicketID, FK - CampusID)
- Campus (PK - CampusID, FK - TechID)
- User (PK - TechID)

I don't think I set up my models correctly as I am showing a ticket where the `CampusID` doesn't belong to the `TechID`. I am looking for a best practice on setting up Eloquent to keep the data integrity in place so I can prevent any abnormalities. As mentioned above the foreign key for `Tickets` should reference the `Campus` primary key, and `Campus` foreign key should reference the `User` primary key.

Here are my `Models`:

**Ticket**

```
protected $table='tickets';

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**Campus**

```
protected $table='campus';

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**User**

```
public function campus()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Campus::class, 'TechID');
}

public function ticket()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class, 'AssignedTo');
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Campus;
use App\Ticket;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    // Dashboard Page
    public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $campuses = Campus::where('TechID',$user->id)->pluck('CampusName');
        $tickets = Ticket::all()->where('AssignedTo', $user->id);

        return view('home')->with(['user' => $user,'campuses'=>$campuses,'tickets'=>$tickets]);
    }
    // Queue Page
    public function Queue() {
        return view('Pages.Queue');
    }
    // Reports Page
    public function Reports() {
        return view('Pages.Reports');
    }
    // Search Page
    public function Search() {
        return view('Pages.Search');
    }
}
```

I think my models are fine, but my controller is probably where I made some mistakes. I've tried reading questions on here already, watching videos, and reading the Laravel docs, but nothing has really clicked with me yet. I really appreciate any and all help. Ideally it should cascade changes. So if I have a situation where I want to change what location a tech belongs to I could just make the change in the `Campus` table probably in the `TechID` column.

Comment: Since your keys aren't in a Laravel-expected format, you'll need to specify both keys on the relationship. It's usually `class, foreign_key, local_key`

Comment: @aynber just for giggles, what is the expected format? Thank you for your input

Comment: The expected format is snake case, all lowercase, with the primary key for each table as just `id`, and foreign keys as `table_id`, such as `user_id` or `campus_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

```
public function index()
{
    $user = User::with([
        'campuses' => function($query) {
           $query->select(['id', 'CampusName']);     
        }, 
        'tickets'
      ])->where('id', Auth::id())->first();

    $campuses = $user->campuses->pluck('CampusName');
    $tickets = Ticket::all()->where('AssignedTo', $user->id);

    return view('home')->with([
       'user' => $user,
       'campuses'=>$user->campuses->pluck('CampusName'),
       'tickets'=>$user->tickets]);
}
```

## EDIT

You need to update your User model.

```
public function campuses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Campus::class, 'TechID');
}

public function tickets()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class, 'AssignedTo');
}
```

Comment: I tried this out and ran into the error `Call to undefined relationship [campuses] on model [App\User]` Is this because `CampusName` column doesn't exist in the Ticket table?

Comment: Also is Eager loading like creating an object with things like `CampusName` as properties?

Comment: Eager loading fetches the relationship with the initial request. Check out the link I posted, it goes into detail.

Comment: Is there a way to change where the tickets rely on the `CampusID` instead of the `AssignedTo` column? I tried to change `Ticket::all()->where('AssignedTo', $user->id);` to `Ticket::all()->where('CampusID', $user->campuses->pluck('CampusID');` So for example, let's say a user changes what campus they belong to, in theory I would just have to change the `TechID` column within the `campus` table and only the tickets would show if the campus is assigned to that tech instead of if the ticket is assigned to that tech

Comment: That feels like another question with some more detail on what you are trying to do.