# How to create a relationship between models for ticket system in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to make a ticketing system and I am working on showing the tickets a user has. The way the relationship works now is that the tickets are assigned to a user who's then assigned to a campus. I actually need it to to be where the tickets are assigned to the campus since the campus is definite, and have a tech assigned to that campus. The tech should only see the tickets that belongs to the campus that the tech is assigned to.

In theory, it should work like if a user is changed or relocated then all that needs to be done is update the `TechID` column. Here is how the table relationship works currently:

- Tickets (PK - TicketID, FK - CampusID)
- Campus (PK - CampusID, FK - TechID)
- User (PK - TechID)

I actually have a similar question that I asked before, but this was before I realized that the way it was structured before isn't the ideal setup.

Here is the link to the previous question: [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53838769/how-to-join-three-tables-with-laravel-and-keep-data-integrity/53838905?noredirect=1#comment94531558_53838905)

Here is my current controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Campus;
use App\Ticket;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    // Dashboard Page
    public function index()
    {
    $user = User::with(['campuses' => function($query) {
        $query->select(['TechID', 'CampusName']);
    },'tickets'])->where('id', Auth::id())->first();

    $campuses = Campus::all()->where('TechID', $user->id);
    $tickets = Ticket::all()->where('CampusID', $campuses->pluck('CampusID'));

    return view('home')->with([
       'user' => $user,
       'campuses'=>$campuses,
       'tickets'=>$tickets]);
    }
    // Queue Page
    public function Queue() {
        return view('Pages.Queue');
    }
    // Reports Page
    public function Reports() {
        return view('Pages.Reports');
    }
    // Search Page
    public function Search() {
        return view('Pages.Search');
    }
}
```

I was hoping this would work, but no tickets actually show up. The user can have more than one campus so I was wondering if maybe this is where things are messing up. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Try doing the where before the all, and use `whereIn('CampusID', $campuses->pluck('CampusID'))`

Comment: Your code is pretty unclear.  Why are you eager loading campuses and tickets and then doing another query later to pull ALL of the campuses and tickets?   You do realize that all() will retrieve everything  from your table and then you're filtering it through a collection method?   Might want to consult the docs a bit more.

Comment: Gonna be honest @Devon, I'm completely green to Laravel. I'm not familiar with eager loading. From what you're saying I do agree with you

Comment: @aynber thank you I will give that a shot

Comment: Well, you should probably read the docs before using Laravel.  It's fairly well documented and it's a pretty large framework to just pick up.

Comment: @Devon I've taken a good read so far, I just don't understand eager loading. Been following along with Laracast as well. Thank you for your suggestion, I do appreciate it

Comment: @aynber your suggestion worked, can you put that as an answer please?

Comment: It'd be hard to explain unless you've read through the relationships section and understand how Eloquent works.  Eager loading is done with the `with` method and loads the relationship data (related models) prior to you accessing the related property.   The other issue is you should never really use all() in an application.  Filtering data in PHP via collection methods is horribly inefficient compared to filtering data in your database via the query builder.  If you don't know what the differences are between collections and the query builder, you need to do more reading of the docs.

Comment: @Devon Thank you, again I really appreciate your input. This really gives me a good idea on where to start and correct some misinformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest doing the where before the all/get, so that the filtering is done on the database level instead of PHP -- `all` before `where` will have the database return all of the values, then use the `Collection` to filter the results. Also, the second query needs whereIn, since you're passing in an array of values:

```
$campuses = Campus::where('TechID', $user->id)->get();
$tickets = Ticket::whereIn('CampusID', $campuses->pluck('CampusID'))->get();
```